# setOnClickListener in a button inside a ListView Event

Tags: android

I've to make a `setOnClickListener` inside a `setOnItemClickListener`, but when Implement the method I have to make double touch, one for the method in the `setOnItemClickListener` and another for the `setOnClickListener`, i would like, just to make one touch. Does anyone knows how I've to do that?

this is part of my code:

```
lv_tarjetas_usuario_mant.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

                img1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_editar_beneficiario);
                img2 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_eliminar_beneficiario);

                img1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        id_tarjeta = tarjetasMantenimientoAdapater.getItem(position).getIdTarjeta();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ListadoTarjetasUsuario.this, ActualizarTarjeta.class);
                        intent.putExtra("id_tarjeta", id_tarjeta);
                        intent.putExtra("usuario", usuario);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                });

                img2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        id_tarjeta = tarjetasMantenimientoAdapater.getItem(position).getIdTarjeta();
                        queDeseaHacer();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Are you using custom Adapter..?

Comment: you have to use a custom adapter that takes in a separate layout view. that is where you control the list view in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

you should use **RecyclerView** This is only way to do this action.